# easy_install prefix option does not work

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, easy-install

```
# echo $PYTHONPATH
 /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages
# whoami
 root
# easy_install --prefix=/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages django==1.9
 TEST FAILED: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/lib/python2.7/site-packages does NOT support .pth files
 error: bad install directory or PYTHONPATH

 You are attempting to install a package to a directory that is not
 on PYTHONPATH and which Python does not read ".pth" files from.  The
 installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
 the distutils default setting) was:

    /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/lib/python2.7/site-packages

 and your PYTHONPATH environment variable currently contains:

    '/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages'

 Here are some of your options for correcting the problem:

 * You can choose a different installation directory, i.e., one that is
  on PYTHONPATH or supports .pth files

 * You can add the installation directory to the PYTHONPATH environment
  variable.  (It must then also be on PYTHONPATH whenever you run
  Python and want to use the package(s) you are installing.)

 * You can set up the installation directory to support ".pth" files by
  using one of the approaches described here:

    https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/easy_install.html#custom-installation-locations

 Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.
# ls /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/lib/python2.7/site-packages
#
```

---

After reading [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10010095/3317808), I couldn't  find `.pydistutils.cfg` file in the file system

`easy_install` command tries to install in install path`/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/lib/python2.7/site-packages` which is invalid. This install path is getting created, amidst `easy_install`

---

**Question:**

How to resolve the install path using easy_install?

Answer (score 0):

1.Are you using easy_install that works with Python2? Try to use easy_install that works with Python3.

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849762/python-3-easy-install-pip-and-pypi).

2.`--prefix` set installation prefix.
When you use `easy_install --prefix=/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages`,
the dir is :

```
'/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/' + 'lib/python2.7/site-packages'
```

Maybe you should use `--install-dir`

Comment: Provided link gives 404 Not found

Comment: @overexchange, I test the link, it works.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849762/python-3-easy-install-pip-and-pypi

Comment: Command(wget https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py) gives 404 not found. request-URI is wrong, I guess

Comment: [Here](http://svn.python.org/projects/sandbox/branches/setuptools-0.6/EasyInstall.txt), it talks about creating `.pydistutils.cfg` file